# Error in the first line of the Python (Maya 2022) script. (# Error: SyntaxError: file <maya console> line 1: invalid syntax)

Tags: python, import, maya

The script for Autodesk Maya 2022 does not work because of an error. I didn't get to the script because I can't import the script. Two lines:

```
import ymd_enhancedPlayblast
ymd_enhancedPlayblast.main()
```

On the first line there is an error

## Error: SyntaxError: file  line 1: invalid syntax

I retyped the line from the documentation, didn't help. I don't have time to dive into Python, I need to occasionally run a finished script. Who can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't even know what you want. My Python script doesn't work because of an error. I need the script to work. Why is the script not working?

Comment: Did you acciedently try it in a mel tab instead of a python script tab?